# $F(x)=\int_{-2}^x|t+1|e^tdt$ find F(x)?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**The Problem**

> Find
>   $$F(x)=\int_{-2}^x|t+1|e^tdt$$

**Approach**

I can just integrate it but wasn't so sure how to treat the absolute function
and I try to separate the absolute value

For $x \le -1$,
$$F(x)=\int_{-2}^x-(t+1)e^t \ dt$$
and for $x>-1$,
$$F(x)=\int_{-1}^x(t+1)e^t \ dt$$

Is my approach correct? Does this problem require fundamental theorem of calculus? I wasn't so sure how to separate the function because the upper bound is $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First part is correct, in second part for $x > -1$ $$F(x)=\int_{-2}^{-1}-(t+1)e^tdt+\int_{-1}^x(t+1)e^tdt$$

Comment: thanks but could you give me hint? $F(x)=\int_{-2}^{-1}-(t+1)e^tdt+$ how can i get this part?

Comment: you have to do integration by parts to get the value. We have this part because since $x > -1$ has a different function under the integration sign from when $x \le -1$

Comment: $t+1>0$, $\int_{-2}^x(t+1)e^t \ dt$ and $t+1<0$ , $\int_{-2}^x-(t+1)e^t \ dt$, is it correc tif i write like this? what do you mean by different function? is this mean that there are two cases, first one is -2<x<-1 and second one is when x>-1>-2  in the graph?

Comment: See that an absolute value function is defined differently at different values so that the function is always positive. You can't write it as you have shown. For $t\in(-2,-1)$ the function in integration sign is $-(t+1)e^t$, and for $t\in(-1,\infty)$ the function is $(t+1)e^t$, $F(x)$ is defined as the integration over $t$ in the range $(-2,x)$, now in this range of $t$ the function changes at $-1$ so that resulting function is positive for that value of $t$ hence you need to break the range to do the integration.

Comment: For $ t∈(−2,−1) $the function in integration sign is$ −(t+1)e^t$, and for $t∈(−1,∞)$ the function is $(t+1)e^t$ , i will break the integration in range $(-2,x)$ when $x \le -1$, the function in integration sign is$ −(t+1)e^t$. and when $x >1$ it will be range from $(-2, x)$ so the function in integration will be $(-2,-1)$  with negative sign $ −(t+1)e^t$, and $(-1,x)$ with positive sign  $(t+1)e^t$ right??

Comment: Yeah sounds about t

Comment: thankyou so much!!!!